# error > /home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/api.py(685)call_kw() -> method = getattr(type(model), name) (Pdb) statusbar odoo module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm working on a module in odoo that allows the change of states.

The data  register is ok, but i would  like change the state of register.

I do not know what's wrong

**statusbar_model.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
from odoo import models, fields, api
class statusbar(models.Model):
    _name = 'statusbar.demo'
    name = fields.Char('Name', required=True)

    state = fields.Selection([
            ('concept', 'Concept'),
            ('started', 'Started'),
            ('progress', 'In progress'),
            ('finished', 'Done'),
            ],default='concept')

    @api.multi
    def concept_progressbar(self):
        self.state = 'concept'

    @api.multi
    def started_progressbar(self):
        self.state = 'started'

    @api.multi
    def progress_progressbar(self):
        self.state = 'progress'

    @api.multi
    def done_progressbar(self):
        self.state = 'finished'enter code here
```

**statusbar_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo> 
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_statusbar_form">
        <field name="name">Statusbar</field>
        <field name="model">statusbar.demo</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Workflow record">

            <header>
                <button string="Set to concept" type="object" name="concept_progressbar" 
attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '=', 'concept')]}"/>

                <button string="Set to started" type="object" name="started_progressbar" 
class="oe_highlight" attrs="{'invisible': [('state','!=','concept')]}"/>
                <button string="In progress" type="object" name="progress_progressbar" 
attrs="{'invisible': [('state','=','progress')]}"/>
                <button string="Done" type="object" name="done_progressbar" attrs="
{'invisible': [('state','=','finished')]}"/>
                <!--This will create the statusbar, thanks to the widget. -->
                <field name="state" widget="statusbar"/>
            </header>
            <group>
                <field name="name"/>
            </group>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

but for example when I click on set to start

[image]

get this error:

```
> /home/odoo/odoo-dev/odoo/odoo/api.py(685)call_kw()
-> method = getattr(type(model), name)
(Pdb)
```

any help is welcome thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could use in every method:

```
self.write({'state': 'key_state_selected'})
return True #to update the view
```

I hope this can be helful for you.